# how to add custom info to junit5 HTML test report?

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

Is it possible to add (log) custom information in HTML report for the passed test in Junit5 ?

I tried to use org.junit.jupiter.api.TestReporter from
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection

but the published report entry is nowhere to be found.  Generated HTML report has just information about name, duration and status of the test.

edit: any standard way of producing report is fine for me, as long as I would be able to insert some custom data. I tried generating report by gradle plugin and by ant task **junitreport**

Comment: How do you produce the reports? The commandline runner, Gradle and Maven all do it differently.

Comment: @johanneslink I edited the question. Sofar I tried producing report by gradle and Ant. But I am fine with any way of producing report.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the console launcher https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher with option ˋ—reports-dir=DIRˋ included report entries in the produced xml reports. Behaviour might have changed though, so you’ll have to try.

Comment: I am using ConsoleLauncher with —reports-dir option, but generated HTML does not have custom entries inserted by TestReporter.